# Firefox Unable to Update in Kail Linux

Tags: firefox, browser, linux

I've installed Firefox 52.0.1 (64-bit) on a latest updated Kali Linux machine in a non-root user. The problem is firefox tries to automatically update in the background but fails popping this message:

> You do not have the system permissions required to install it.

Here is the screenshot too.

[image: Screenshot]

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Someone using kali as a non root user? *Awesome*. But for once, that's exactly where your problem is - you probably have firefox installed as a root user with other users allowed to use it.

In theory (and I don't use kali, but assume its sane here) you could simply use your package manager to update firefox. Otherwise run firefox as root (eww) and let it update.